# How to remember Maxwell equation in Gaussian units?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, si-units, unit-conversion

I know Maxwell relation in MKS unit
$$\begin{cases}\nabla\times E=-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t},\\
\nabla \times B = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} + \mu_0J,\\
\nabla\cdot E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0},\\
\nabla\cdot B =0\end{cases}$$

and the derivation of this equation into Gaussian units
$$\begin{cases}\nabla\times E=-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial B}{\partial t},\\
\nabla \times B = \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial E}{\partial t} + \frac{4\pi}{c}J,\\
\nabla\cdot E = 4\pi\rho,\\
\nabla\cdot B =0\end{cases}$$

But I still find the derivation is cumbersome and easy to get it wrong.
How do you memorize the Maxwell equation in the Gaussian units?

Comment: Read [up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units#"Rationalized"_unit_systems).

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to memorize them, I suggest to remember simply two relations
\begin{equation}
\mu_{0}\epsilon_{0} \to \frac{1}{c} \quad \text{and} \quad \epsilon_{0} \to \frac{1}{4\pi}.
\end{equation}
Memorizing this two, you can deduce that $\mu_{0} = 4\pi/c$, which correctly gives the gradient of $E$ and the curl of $B$. From this, it might just take to notice that "your $c$'s must match your $t$'s" and therefore, a $c$ goes also in the term $\partial B/\partial t$ in the curl of $E$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This heuristic is useful in this very limited circumstance, but it's always bothered me because, in fact, $\mu_0\epsilon_0=c^{-2}$.